# Issue with categories in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors, categories

I'am doing some exercises, but can't understand what is wrong.

I have:

Fraction+MathOps.h

```
#import "Fraction.h"

@interface Fraction (MathOps)
-(Fraction *) add:(Fraction *) f;
@end
```

Here is Fraction+MathOps.m

```
#import "Fraction+MathOps.h"

@implementation Fraction (MathOps)

-(Fraction *) add:(Fraction *) f
{
    //To add two fraction
    // a / b + c / d = ((a * b) + (b * c)) / (b * d)

    Fraction *result = [[Fraction alloc] init];

    result.numerator = (self.numerator * f.denominator) + (self.denominator * f.numerator);
    result.denominator = self.denominator * f.numerator;

    [result reduce];

    return result;
}

@end
```

and will try to call method add from categories in main.m

```
Fraction *ca = [[Fraction alloc] init];
Fraction *cb = [[Fraction alloc] init];
Fraction *cresult;

[ca setTo: 1 over: 3];  
[cb setTo: 2 over: 5];  

cresult = [ca add: cb];
```

and have compiler error (No visible @interface for 'Fraction' declares the selector 'add:'
) at cresult = [ca add: cb] string.

Comment: Are you `#include`ing "Fraction+MathOps.h" from main.m?

Comment: Do you have `#import "Fraction+MathOps.h"` in `main.m`?

Comment: Oops, nope. Thanks guys, after including that all works good, thank you! But it is strange I thought Fraction class knows about itself categories.

Comment: @Ju-v: The code will work without the header file, but the compiler will complain, as it can't *know* that the code works unless it processes the header file, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem solved:**
I didn't include Fraction+MathOps.h in main.m 
Thanks Richard and Carl Norum

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across this issue today, with Xcode 7.3.  Using the example above, removing the first line from Fraction+MathOps.m caused Xcode to understand the additional (category) selector without throwing errors.

After removing the #import line from Fraction+MathOps.h, I put it back.  No more issues.

If you see this message, a little creative text editing may cause Xcode to fix the problem for you.